# OWL API getAnnotationObjects method is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, owl, owl-api

I'm trying to run [Simple Hierarchy example of OWL API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/uk/ac/manchester/owl/owlapi/tutorial/examples/SimpleHierarchyExample.java). I included `owlapi-osgidistribution-4.0.2.jar` and all libraries from its lib folder to the project class path. However I still have one unresolved import:

```
import static org.semanticweb.owlapi.search.EntitySearcher.getAnnotationObjects;
```

And one undefined method associated with that import:

```
for (OWLAnnotation anno : getAnnotationObjects(clazz, ontology)) {
    anno.accept(le);
}
```

I see that `EntitySearcher` class is in the OWL API library. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

EntitySearcher is in the owlapi-api module, so should be found in your classpath.

That example is compiled routinely with each owlapi build, so it should not present any particular problem.

Note: I can't recall if the method you mention was added before or after 4.0.2 was released. It is possible that it was added for 4.1.0.

Comment: The problem was library version as you noted. The newest library on sourceforge.net is 4.0.2 and i didn't know that there's higher version available.

Comment: 4.1.0 has not been released yet: it is the version4 branch in GitHub.

Comment: I understand. But in this case i think examples should be compatible with last released version ;)

Comment: Examples from the code associated with the release are :-) they are in the same source tree and compiled with the most recent version so they don't fall out of date. You can check out the 4.0.2 tag to access the correct source.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the exact same instance of the problem yesterday, interesting coincidence.

The code that you're looking at is supposed to work with the latest version of the OWL API, namely 4.1.0-RC4. I've found hints to the problem browsing through the [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/mailman/message/34367910/). Unfortunately the only available packaged version right now is the 4.0.2, and the latest version on the Maven repositories is 4.1.0-RC2, which didn't ship with the method used in the example.

The way I temporarily "solved" the problem was to use the Maven dependencies targeting version 4.1.0-RC2 and adding to the classpath the binary distribution for 4.1.0-RC4 built from the git repository (overriding the one for the older version resolved by Maven).

Assuming you know how to use Maven, this is the relevant entry of the POM file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-osgidistribution</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

To build the latest version of OWL API, just clone the git repository or download it as a zip file, extract and then run `mvn clean install`: the jar you want to add to your classpath should be present in the `./distribution/target/` directory.

You're also likely to get some warnings about the logger, if you want to fix that as well you need to get the tarball of `slf4j` with version matching the one that was resolved by Maven (from [here](http://www.slf4j.org/dist/), the version I used is 1.7.7), build it and then add `slf4j-simple-#.#.#.jar` to your classpath.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, with 4.1.0-RC4 version code example runs fine. I didn't know that there is higher version that 4.0.2 before. However i found out that 4.1.0-RC4 can be easily download here -> https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/sourceforge/owlapi/owlapi-osgidistribution/4.1.0-RC4-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: This links had the exact version of owlapi for 4.1.0 https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/All-Releases